# How to deal with SQLite in an asynchronous project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, system.data.sqlite, microsoft.data.sqlite

SQLite is not asynchronous, and the exposed Microsoft.Data.Sqlite ADO.net `*Async` methods are implemented synchronously under the hood.

My question: how would you use SQLite in a asp.net core 5 API project which could benefit from asynchronous code, and also the async/await keywords to coordinate it?

I see two options

- use the "fake" `*Async` methods, and lose the benefits of asynchronous code for the code parts that touch the db. If I understand correctly, in .net core blocking a thread will not lead to deadlocks (https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html). If I understand correctly that would act like synchronous code executing on a thread pool thread, with the added overhead of the async/await machinery.
- write synchronous code only, and lose the benefits for parts of the code

Which one do you think would be better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would tend to use the synchronous `Async` methods, but it's not a strong preference. The only reason I'd prefer `Async` is just in case either a different database is used in the future, or SQLite gets *real* asynchronous methods in a future release.

What you definitely want to avoid is `await Task.Run`.